# How to increment data in every cell in csv and few questions [Python]

Tags: web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-3.6

I have written a code that that can scrape few details from a webpage. My question is whenever I run my code it prints the output like :

> |['Kapil Sarawagi'     'ksdesigngroup@gmail.com'   '1412702594']| |['MA ARCHICTECTS PRIVATE LIMITED'   'studio@maarchitects.in'    '1414299999']| |['Prabhu Dayal Kanojiya'    'prabhudayalkanojiya@yahoo.in'  '9829055412']|

however I want it to be like:

```
|['Kapil Sarawagi'        'ksdesigngroup@gmail.com'     '1412702594']|

|['MA ARCHICTECTS PRIVATE LIMITED'     'studio@maarchitects.in'   '1414299999']|

|['Prabhu Dayal Kanojiya'     'prabhudayalkanojiya@yahoo.in'  '9829055412']|
```

like in each cell...how can I do this?

Second question, how can I make my code look for professional? Is my coding style bad? And how can I make it shorter?

This is my code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.request import urlopen
import csv

url = "http://www.rera-rajasthan.in/Home/ViewProject?id=JgMAAA"

html = urlopen(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
finaldata = []
data = soup.find_all("div", {"class":"panel-body"})

#filename = "Rajasthan.csv"
#f = open(filename, "r")


for i in data:# to get engineer
    date = i.find_all("table", {"class":"table table-bordered"})
    getname = date[21].find_all("td")
    name = getname[1].text
    email = getname[0].text
    phone = getname[3].text
    sublist = []
    fname = [name, email, phone]
    sublist.append(fname)
    for i in data:# to extract architect
        date = i.find_all("table", {"class":"table table-bordered"})
        getname = date[20].find_all("td")
        name = getname[1].text
        email = getname[0].text
        phone = getname[3].text
        #sublist = []
        fname = [name, email, phone]
        sublist.append(fname)
        for i in data:# to extract contractor
            date = i.find_all("table", {"class":"table table-bordered"})
            getname = date[19].find_all("td")
            name = getname[1].text
            email = getname[0].text
            phone = getname[3].text
            #sublist = []
            fname = [name, email, phone]
            sublist.append(fname)
finaldata.append(sublist)
with open("output.csv", "w")as csvfile:
    writer = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=',',quotechar='|', lineterminator='\n')
    for i in range(0, len(finaldata)):
        writer.writerow(finaldata[i])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A shorter code to achieve the same goal:

```
import requests
from lxml import html

response = requests.get('http://www.rera-rajasthan.in/Home/ViewProject?id=JgMAAA')
tree = html.fromstring(response.content)

# Getting al <h3> tags with 'TableHeading' class
for heading in tree.xpath('//h3[@class="TableHeading"]'):
    # Extracting <h3> heading name/text
    heading_name = heading.xpath('text()')[0]

    # Checking if <h3> heading name has one of these names
    # We only want to get data from the table next to each one of them
    if heading_name in ['CONTRACTOR', 'ARCHITECT', 'STRUCTURAL ENGINEER']:
        # As each table heading has a table below (following-sibling) them
        # We extract the data from that only table (table[1])
        email, name, address, phone = heading.xpath('.//following-sibling::table[1]//tr/td/text()')
        print [name, email, phone]
```

Results:

```
['Prabhu Dayal Kanojiya', 'prabhudayalkanojiya@yahoo.in', '9829055412']
['MA ARCHICTECTS PRIVATE LIMITED', 'studio@maarchitects.in', '1414299999']
['Kapil Sarawagi', 'ksdesigngroup@gmail.com', '1412702594']
```

Comment: Hey! it's very good coding..thank you so much...is my coding style poor? if yes, how can i improve it?

Comment: @Mr.Bones it's ok. Just keep practicing, reading code, and you'll improve your coding skills certainly.